# How to create a higher level of depth than part in document sections

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, parts

I organized my book in the form part/chapter/section, but now I need to create a higher section, so the document would be organized like the following, higherpart/part/chapter/section.

Using the nomenclature of this article: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/sections_and_chapters,
being part a -1 level in document sectioning, I need a -2 level section, with all the following functionalities in Table Of Contents as well.

How can I do this?

Comment: What document class are you using? How are you formatting section/chapter headings. You had added the `titlesec` tag, which has been removed. Are you using it?

Comment: Wouldn't using part/chapter/section/subsection work equally well?

Comment: Answering in order: - I am using the book document class, I put the titlesec tag because I thought it would be necessary for the solution, but it wasn't. For now I am using the solution posted below, without titlesec.

Comment: - Yes it would work equally, but I would have to downgrade part to chapter, chapter to section, etc. That would mess up a lot of styling I've made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume your new sectional unit is called `book`.

You can copy all the components related to `\part` from [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co) and change any reference to `part` to `book`, and also define the appropriate `book` definitions (like a counter its representation). More specifically, you need to

- Copy and update `\part`
- Copy and update `\@part`
- Copy and update `\@spart`
- Copy and update `\@endpart`
- Copy and update `\l@part`
- Create the `book` counter
- Update `\thebook` to suit your needs
- Create `\bookname` (as a counterpart to `\partname` within `\@part` and `\@spart`)

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

% Taken from book.cls:
% https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co
\makeatletter
\newcommand\book{%   <------------- change
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@book\@sbook}%   <------------- change

\def\@book[#1]#2{%   <------------- change
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-3\relax%   <------------- change
      \refstepcounter{book}%   <------------- change
      \addcontentsline{toc}{book}{\thebook\hspace{1em}#1}%   <------------- change
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{book}{#1}%   <------------- change
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \bookname\nobreakspace\thebook%   <------------- change
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endbook}%   <------------- change
\def\@sbook#1{%   <------------- change
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \Huge \bfseries #1\par}%
    \@endbook}%   <------------- change
\def\@endbook{\vfil\newpage%   <------------- change
              \if@twoside
               \if@openright
                \null
                \thispagestyle{empty}%
                \newpage
               \fi
              \fi
              \if@tempswa
                \twocolumn
              \fi}
\newcommand*\l@book[2]{%   <------------- change
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-3\relax%   <------------- change
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      {\leavevmode
       \large \bfseries #1\hfil
       \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2%
                          \kern-\p@\kern\p@}}\par
       \nobreak
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

% Default additions for new sectional unit \book
\newcounter{book}
\renewcommand{\thebook}{\Roman{book}}
\newcommand{\bookname}{Book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\book{A book}

\part{A part}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}

\subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}
```

You'll have to adjust the presentation of the `book` element within the ToC, as well as the main document, to suit your needs.

Note that [`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir) already defines a `book` sectional unit/level in a similar way to what I've done above.

Answer (score 1):

The `memoir` class (a superset of `book`) has 8 divisional levels ranging from `\book`, `part`, `\chapter` down to `\subparagraph`.